# How to perform a partial string query on Dynamics QueryService?

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

> I'm writing this code in C# using Dynamics AIF.

How do I perform a partial string query on Dynamics QueryService?

The Dynamics query would be like this:

```
WHERE %1.Field LIKE '*partialstring*'
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
QueryDataRangeMetadata range = new QueryDataRangeMetadata();
range.FieldName = field;
range.TableName = tableName;
range.Enabled = true;
range.Value = string.Format(" LIKE '*{0}*'", id);
query.DataSources[0].Ranges[0] = range;
```

I thought about this solution because this one works:

```
range.Value = ">2000";
```

But not the one using like... Is there any way to solve this? Any workaround?

According to Joris, in this post http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2013/09/linq-to-ax-example-using-wpf.html you can't perform partial queries on strings using dynamics Linq, I'm having the same problem with the QueryService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already got an answer at https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/148074/333993.aspx from Denis Macchinetti.

Answer:

> Denis Macchinetti responded on 29 Dec 2014 10:32 AM
>
> Hi Eros
>
> In my opinion, you can use a Dynamic Query.
>
> Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg847959.aspx, Dynamic Query
>   section.
>
> Practically, create an AOT class that extends the AifQueryBuilder
>   class.
>
> Then call the QueryServiceClient.ExecuteDynamicQuery method and pass
>   the name of the X++ query class and any query arguments.
>
> An example is the standard class CustTransQueryBuilder.
>
> In this way, you can handle the "like" condition inside AX!
>
> Others link :
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2012/02/17/calling-the-query-service.aspx
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg879657.aspx